# Is it possible to use Diagrams / Graphviz in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphviz

I'm building a python application to generate some AWS Diagrams using Diagrams library ( https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/getting-started/installation )

But in order to use Diagrams, I need to install Graphviz. But as we know, it is not possible to operate in Lambda machines. So is there a way to access Graphviz packges throught Lambda to use Diagram lib?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT] I got source from graphviz and compiled with make. I put the generated dot executable in my code but now dot tries to generate the libs in lambda and lambda does not allow because it is not /tmp folder

[EDIT2] I was able to compile the libs but now I stucked at this error:

```
  Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot
```

I tried to add manually gd libs. It worked on EC2 machine but in lambda don't. If I run the same dot executable in EC2, appears png format. I think png lib are dynamically loaded anyway. So it makes impossible to do this at lambda.

Comment: A web search found this: [Deploying Graphviz on AWS Lambda | Life in plain text](https://lifeinplaintextblog.wordpress.com/deploying-graphviz-on-aws-lambda/)

Comment: I have seen this guide and I tried to do something similar. The version of graphviz which this tutorial uses works but it does not create .png images which is my case. So I tried to compile a newer version but now I'm stucked that graphviz tries to create a lib folder but Lambda only allow to write on /tmp folder 

 " [stderr: b'mkdir: cannot create directory \\xe2\\x80\\x98/var/task/app/.libs\\xe2\\x80\\x99: Read-only file system\\n/var/task/app/dot: "

Comment: News: I was able to pass this problem but now I receive this: '[stderr: b'dot: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.7' In some research, a lot of peoples says that is a missing packge that need to be installed in the machine. Because I don't have this access in Lambda, I suppose that is not possible to run graphviz anyway :/